# Cache memory causing duplicates restricting merge to happen in Fabric notebook

Tags: caching, spark-notebook, microsoft-fabric

I'm encountering an issue with a merge operation in a notebook, where I'm accessing tables from a lakehouse. The merge command fails with a duplicate error. However, when I query the table using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) connected to the lakehouse, it shows zero duplicates. I suspected a caching problem and attempted to resolve it by disabling the cache using the following code:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.synapse.vegas.useCache", "false")

df.cache()

df.unpersist()
```

I also manually switched environments within the notebook and found no duplicates. The perplexing aspect is that the issue persists when the notebook is triggered via a pipeline, even though there are no duplicates when tested manually. What could be the potential reasons behind this discrepancy, and how can it be addressed?

```
spark.conf.set("spark.synapse.vegas.useCache", "false")

df.cache()

df.unpersist()
```

Sample merge code looks like below

```
%%sql
MERGE INTO lakehouse2.table1 AS Target
USING ViewCreatedOnTable2InAnotherLakeHouse AS Source
ON Target.Col1=Source.Col1 and Target.Col2=Source.Col2
```

When  matched then update set

```
Target.col3=Source.Colum3,
Target.Col4=Source.Col4
```

when Not Matched then Insert

```
(col1,col2,col3,col4)
Values(Source.col1,Source.Col2,Source.Col3,Source.Col4)
```

the notebook is using sparksql and scala